# Detecting analog stick is being used

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
private Vector3 GroundVelocity(ref Vector3 vel)
{
    m_animator.SetBool("onGround", true);

    Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);

    bool kbRun = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && m_controller.isGrounded;
    bool gpRun = Mathf.Abs(input.x) > 0.5f && m_controller.isGrounded;
    var sortInputType = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) ^ Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) ? kbRun : gpRun;

    float targetSpeed = ((sortInputType) ? m_runSpeed : m_walkSpeed) * input.x;
    m_curSpd = Mathf.SmoothDamp(m_curSpd, targetSpeed, ref m_speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(m_speedSmoothTime * 3) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * m_playerTime);

    m_animSpdPer = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, m_curSpd);

    vel = new Vector3(m_curSpd, 0, 0);

    return vel;
}
```

My character controller uses both gamepad and keyboard and mouse configuration. Above is how I'm getting the ground velocity for CharacterController.Move().

The issue with this is that when I move horizontally via 'A' and 'D' key when unity detects neither of A and D pressed the target speed is momentarily set to m_runSpeed then goes to stop. The gamepad-side is working as intended. I clearly need a better way to determine the boolean, but I'm out of ideas.

In my opinion, if I could detect the analog stick is being used I could do this, but I don't think I'm going the right way.

Any suggestion for modification or guide would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look in the Edit / InputManager at the Horizontal axis, you'll see there are two by default.  The one for the keyboard and one for the joystick:

[image]

There's nothing stopping you from, say, renaming the key based one to HorizontalKeys and then in your code you could search for both of those separately.  That way if the regular Horizontal has a non-zero Vector2, you'll know it was the controller variant that got used, and if the HorizontalKeys has non-zero then it was that one.

Another option to look at, if what you're trying to achieve is similar speed behaviour across both controls, is potentially leaving them as they are, but tweaking the sensitivity and dead zone on the keyboard one to be more like the controller one.  Then you wouldn't even need to know which of the two was used, the same line of code reading from Horizontal should lerp the same for both.